# MS Word advanced search and replace

Tags: search, replace, ms-word, wildcard

How can I search and replace for format, using wildcards, replacing the found text with the same text with something before and after the whole string, and not before and after each subsequently-found character?

I know that `?` will find any character, and I can then set the format as I wish. The problem is that I want to look for some bold text and place something before the first bold caracter and then something else at the end of the last bold character, provided the bold continues without interruptions. The `?` query would find each bold character.

Example:

T**h**is i**s** the te**xt**

What I want:

`T<bef>h</aft>is i<bef>s</aft> the te<bef>xt</aft>`

And not

`T<bef>h</aft>is i<bef>s</aft> the te<bef>x</aft><bef>t</aft>`

Comment: If you think the downvote makes sense then please also state why my question doesn't show effort or is unclear. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Without **wildcard**, can you accept? How about VBA?

```vb
Sub MS_Word_advanced_search_and_replace()
    Dim a As Range, d As Document, i As Long, ur As UndoRecord, a1 As Range
    Set ur = Word.Application.UndoRecord
    ur.StartCustomRecord "MS_Word_advanced_search_and_replace"
    Word.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set d = ActiveDocument
    Set a = d.Range
    With a.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        While .Execute
            a.Text = "<bef>" + a.Text + "</aft>"
        Wend
    End With

    ur.EndCustomRecord
    Word.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Or:

```vb
Sub MS_Word_advanced_search_and_replace()
    Dim a As Range, d As Document, i As Long, ur As UndoRecord, a1 As Range
    Set ur = Word.Application.UndoRecord
    ur.StartCustomRecord "MS_Word_advanced_search_and_replace"
    Word.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set d = ActiveDocument
    Set a = d.Range
    With a.Find
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        While .Execute
            If a.Bold Then
                i = a.Start
                If Not a.Next Is Nothing Then
                    If Not a.Next.Bold Then
                        Set a1 = a.Next
                        With a1
                            '.InsertBefore "</aft>"
                            .Text = "</aft>" + .Text
    '                        .Bold = False
    '                        .Characters(a1.Characters.Count).Bold = False
                        End With
                        i = i + VBA.Len("</aft>")
                    End If
                End If
                If i > 1 Then
                    If Not a.Previous.Bold Then
                        Set a1 = a.Previous
                        With a1
                            '.InsertAfter "<bef>"
                            .Text = .Text + "<bef>"
                        End With
                        i = i + VBA.Len("<bef>")
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            i = i + 1
            a.SetRange i, i
        Wend
    End With

    ur.EndCustomRecord
    Word.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Much slower and less effective:

```vb
Sub MS_Word_advanced_search_and_replace()
    Dim a As Range, d As Document, i As Long, ur As UndoRecord, iEnd As Long, a1 As Range
    Set ur = Word.Application.UndoRecord
    ur.StartCustomRecord "MS_Word_advanced_search_and_replace"
    Word.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set d = ActiveDocument
    iEnd = d.Range.Characters.Count
    i = 1
    While i < iEnd
        Set a = d.Range.Characters(i)
        If a.Bold Then
            If i < d.Range.Characters.Count Then
                If Not a.Next.Bold Then
                    Set a1 = a.Next
                    With a1
                        '.InsertBefore "</aft>"
                        .Text = "</aft>" + .Text
'                        .Bold = False
'                        .Characters(a1.Characters.Count).Bold = False
                    End With
                    i = i + VBA.Len("</aft>")
                End If
            End If
            If i > 1 Then
                If Not a.Previous.Bold Then
                    Set a1 = a.Previous
                    With a1
                        '.InsertAfter "<bef>"
                        .Text = .Text + "<bef>"
                    End With
                    i = i + VBA.Len("<bef>")
                End If
            End If
        End If
        iEnd = d.Range.Characters.Count
        i = i + 1
    Wend
    ur.EndCustomRecord
    Word.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```